# How can I write the output of .describe() for a df column to a new df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe for which I would like to pull the statistics on a particular column using .describe() and write the output to a new df.  I also need to group the output of .describe() by another column ('SITE' in this case) in the source df. Below is the code I tried as well as the error message.

```
df5 = df.groupby('SITE')['DSKPERCENT'].describe().apply(lambda x: format(x, 'f')).to_frame(name='SITE_DESCRIBE').reset_index()
```

```
df5 = data.groupby('SITE')['DSKPERCENT'].describe().apply(lambda x: format(x, 'f')).to_frame(name='SITE_DESCRIBE').reset_index()
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__
```

My assumption is that the output of .describe() is a list of values rather than a single value.  How can I work around this and get the desired output?

Comment: Please share a sample input dataframe with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data.groupby('SITE')['DSKPERCENT']` is a Series, (check it with  `type(data.groupby('SITE')['DSKPERCENT']`) `.describre()` will return a Series.

If you want a DataFrame you could do:

```
pd.DataFrame( some_df['some_column'].describe() )
```

You say "I also need to group the output of .describe() by another column ('SITE' in this case)"

But by doing `df.groupby('SITE')['DSKPERCENT'].describe()` you are describing the output of the groupby

Comment: @motirx, thanks.  What im trying to get too is, a new df that holds the output of .describe() for each location in the 'SITE' column, for the values held for that site in the 'DSKPERCENT' column.

Comment: Isn't it then `df.groupby('SITE')['DSKPERCENT'].describe()` what you want? The output of that should already be a DataFrame